# Validate two form fields are same before submitting

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am trying to get this form to only submit if the two form fields have the same values. It is working correctly in another form, but this one is bypassing the fields check and just submitting.

```
    <form id="accounts-user-form" style="display: none;" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header-panel">
            <h2>New User</h2>
            <div class="box-icon" id="accounts-user-form-close">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-content">
                    <div class="step-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">


                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            Title
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input id="selectError9" class="form-control col-xs-6" data-bind="value:UserHolder.Title" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            First Name
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input id="selectError10" class="form-control col-xs-6" data-bind="value: UserHolder.FirstName" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            Last Name
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input id="selectError11" class="form-control col-xs-6" data-bind="value: UserHolder.LastName" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            Email
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input id="selectError11" class="form-control col-xs-6" data-bind="value: UserHolder.Email" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            Phone
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="selectError12" class="form-control col-xs-6" data-bind="value: UserHolder.Phone" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Phone Type
                                        <div class="controls">
                                        <select id='selectError13' class='form-control' data-bind="value: UserHolder.PhoneTypeId"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Contact Type
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select id='selectError14' class='form-control' data-bind="value: UserHolder.ContactTypeId"></select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Password
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control col-xs-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        Confirm
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="password_again" type="password" class="form-control col-xs-6">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input id="selectError16" type="password" class="form-control col-xs-6 password-hidden" data-bind="value: UserHolder.Password">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-content">
                    <button id="btn_add_user_large" class='btn btn-large btn-primary btn-round' name="submit">Add User <i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-down'></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

jQUERY:

```
$('#btn_add_user_large').click(function () {
        var isvalidate = $("#accounts-user-form").valid();
        if (isvalidate) {
            addUser();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

$("#accounts-user-form").validate({
    rules: {
        password: "required",
        password_again: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have failed to include a `name` attribute on your input elements.  This plugin requires that inputs with validation have a unique `name`.

```
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control col-xs-6">
<input id="password_again" name="password_again" type="password" class="form-control col-xs-6">
```

The `rules` option uses the field `name`...

```
rules: {
    password: "required",  // <- the field has name="password"
    password_again: {      // <- the field has name="password_again"
        equalTo: "#password"
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/HE5t8/1/**